# Using Javascript to identify computer on network

Tags: javascript

I am using jsPrintSetup on Firefox to silently print receipts. We are adding a second point of sale/receipt printer. I therefore need to be able to use JS to identify which of the two POS computers is running the print script in order that the correct receipt printer can be selected. Is there an easy way of doing this? I have considered javascript cookies, but these would be susceptible to someone clearing the browsers cookies.
Any ideas would be gratefully received.

Many thanks

Comment: Can't you just send a custom parameter with your request?

Comment: Just ask the user which POS he works at when the cookie/localstorage/whatever kind of persistence mechanism you use does not have it stored? You'll need to do it at least once for setup anyway.